# how to find what is between a number that is followed by a # and ends in another # in notepad ++ and replace the result into another file

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is what I got:

```
.*([1-30000]#.*#).*
```

However, I would like to follow these rules without limiting to only 1 line.

For example, using: `.*([1-30000]#.*#).*` I could find:

```
5173#bunch of text here#
```

And what I would like to find:

```
5173#bunch of text here
of, bunch here, text
text here, bunch of
#
```

Hope I managed to be clear about my problem, thanks for the help.

Edit:

```
\b(?:[12]?\d{1,4}|30{4})#[^#]+#
```

Seems to be working, now the "challenge" is another, i want to save the number before the # (5173#) and replace what i got into another file where the same number is found.

Comment: Is the number always four digits?

Comment: You can't match a range of digits among 1 to 30K using `[1-30000]`. `[1-30000]` is equal to `[1-30]` which is `[1230]` which is `[0-3]`. You need a regex similar to this one `\b(?:[12]?\d{1,4}|30{4})#[^#]*#`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/4A1b4X/1

Comment: Try [`.*?([0-9]+#[^#]*#).*`](https://regex101.com/r/HgAdhx/1)

Comment: .*?([0-9]+#[^#]*#).* Selected the whole file

Comment: \b(?:[12]?\d{1,4}|30{4})# Selected only the beggining

Comment: @AndrewCarrazzone You copied the regex partially. If you look at the rest of my comment you will see regex continues in the next line.

Comment: @revo , Indeed, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?<=\d#)[^#]+
```

Enable `. matches newline` and regex in your NP++ search box.

This matches text preceded by only a single digit followed by a pound and succeeded by a pound since NP++ doesn't support variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: I think OP is looking for the text between the two `#`

Comment: Perhaps just `(?<=\d#)[^#]+`

Comment: (?<=\d#)[^#]+ Worked almost perfectly because i also need to select the number before the first #

Answer (score 0):

With the contribution of all, that is, joining what was answered by you. I got:

```
\b(?:[12]?\d{1,4}|30{4})#[^#]+#
```

I'm not sure if there's any mistake, I'm not familiar with all of this. :)
https://regex101.com/r/t7xBXk/1